# Switch statement nested format - which is correct?

Tags: ios, objective-c, switch-statement

I often use nested cases and I wrap them with { }. My question is which of these are correct? Both seems to work fine.

```
switch (yourMom) {
  case 1: {
     // so fat
  }
  break;

  default:
  break;

}
```

OR

```
switch (yourMom) {
  case 1: {
     // so fat
  break;
  }
  default:
  break;

}
```

Comment: I believe that its more about preference. I tend to use the first one though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are equivalent.

The braces are merely defining scope, and `break` is not subject to scoping.

For what it's worth, I tend to use the first of your two cases; as it's a little clearer to the reader that the case labels do not follow through to each other.

(You'd need the braces if `case 1` for example was declaring a variable.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I, too, use the first one. It makes more sense.